# How do you disable the XBox 360 Halo 4 Edition Startup Sound?

Tags: xbox-360

The XBOX 360 Halo 4 Limited Edition Console has a cheesy action-game sound every time you startup/shutdown the console.

Is there any way to disable this? I'd be willing to open this thing up and rip out its internal speaker if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to disable it, per [this thread](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-258682.html) and [comments on this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjFYW3cynGk).  However, there is a fairly easy workaround:

There are only two sources of the sounds, driven by hardware.  The sounds is played when you physically touch the system.

**For Power On**: Use the XBox button on your controller.

**For Disc eject, close**: Just navigate to Open/Close Tray via the 360 dashboard.

**For Power Off**: Navigate to Setting -> Turn Off.

If rewiring is more your thing, there is a tutorial on adding a new sound board to your box [here](http://team-xecuter.com/forums/showthread.php?t=90412).

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be into [hacking the console and flashing the BIOS.](http://forums.xbox-scene.com/index.php?showtopic=498480)

Comment: Does this count as modding the console? Could this get the user banned?

Comment: You would have to assume yes.